# Getting 404 error instead of 401, when token is expired or when token is not passed Asp.net core 2

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, bearer-token

I created Asp.net-core 2 project and added

1. api controller authorized by Bearer token.
2. mvc controllers authorized by
   CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme.
3. don't have app.UseIdentity();  in Configure functions

When i tried to call api published in iis express .it will returned 401 unauthorized .

When i tried to call api published in iis.it will returned 404 not found.

I am Getting 404 error instead of 401, when token is expired or when token is not passed

and my startup

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApiContext>();
        //options =>
        //    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddTransient<ApiContextSeed>();
        //a confirmed email.
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            config.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            config.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            config.Password.RequiredUniqueChars =0;
            config.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            config.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null;

        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApiContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
        services.AddResponseCaching();
        services.AddAutoMapper();
        services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.AddSingleton<IWizIQSender, WizIQSender>();
        services.AddSingleton<IWizIQClass, WizIQClass>();
        services.AddSingleton<ITimeZone, TimeZone>();
        services.AddSingleton<IPinCodeGenerator, PinCodeGenerator>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWorkAsync>();
        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
        services.AddBootstrapPagerGenerator(options =>
        {
            // Use default pager options.
            options.ConfigureDefault();
        });         
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

              .AddCookie("UserAuth", options =>
        {

            options.LoginPath = string.Empty;



        });      
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();         
        #region FlashMessage

        services.AddSession();
        // Needed so we can access the user's session.
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddScoped(x => x.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.Session);

        services.AddScoped<IMessageProvider, SessionMessageProvider>();

        // Customize the message types (i.e. we are using Bootstrap v3 and need to provide a custom-value for the error message-type).
        services.AddScoped<IMessageTypes>(x =>
        {
            return new MessageTypes(error: "danger");
        });

        services.AddScoped<IMessengerOptions, MessengerOptions>();

        // We are using a stack to hold messages (i.e. LIFO).
        services.AddScoped<IMessenger, StackMessenger>();

        #endregion
        services.AddCors(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddPolicy("UserPanel", bldr =>
            {
                bldr.AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin();
            });
        });
        //using JWT
        services.AddAuthentication()
              .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
              {
                  cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                  cfg.SaveToken = true;
                  cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                  {
                      ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                      ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],  
                      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"]))
                  };

              });


        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        //services.AddUrlHelper();
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "Drossey API", Version = "v1" });
        });


    } 

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ApiContextSeed seeding)
   {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
             app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error");

        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();       
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseCors("UserPanel");
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Drossey Api");
        });
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {            
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "areaRoute",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });           
        seeding.EnsureSeeding().Wait();
    }
```

and this my api controller

```
public class CodeController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IPinCodeGenerator _pinCodeGenerator;

    public CodeController(IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWork,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userMgr, IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> hasher, 
        ILogger<AuthController> logger, IConfiguration config, IMapper mapper, IPinCodeGenerator pinCodeGenerator) :
        base(unitOfWork, userMgr, hasher, logger, config, mapper)
    {
        _pinCodeGenerator = pinCodeGenerator;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody]CodeAddViewModel model)
    {

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var userId = await GetUserId();
                var user = await _userMgr.FindByIdAsync(userId);

                var random = Convert.ToDouble(model.Code.Substring(0, 10));
                var code = model.Code.Substring(10, 5);
                var pinCode = _unitOfWork.PinCodeRepository.Filter(u => u.Code == random).FirstOrDefault();
                if (pinCode == null || pinCode.Status != CodeStatus.IsActive)
                {
                    return StatusCode(400, "InValidCode");
                }
                else
                {
                    string codeStr = _pinCodeGenerator.GetCode(pinCode.Amount, pinCode.Code,
                        pinCode.Vector, pinCode.Key);
                    if (codeStr != model.Code)
                    {
                        return StatusCode(400, "InValidCode");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        user.Balance += pinCode.Amount;
                        await _userMgr.UpdateAsync(user);
                        pinCode.Status = CodeStatus.Shipped;
                        await _unitOfWork.CommitAsync();
                        return Ok();

                    }
                }

            }
            return StatusCode(400, ModelState);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return StatusCode(500, e.Message);
        }



    }
}
```

and base controller contains

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public readonly ILogger<AuthController> _logger;
    public readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInMgr;
    public readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userMgr;
    public readonly IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> _hasher;
    public readonly IConfiguration _config;
    public IUnitOfWorkAsync _unitOfWork;
    protected readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public BaseController(IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWork,

        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userMgr,
        IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> hasher,
        ILogger<AuthController> logger,
        IConfiguration config,
        IMapper mapper
        )
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        //_signInMgr = signInMgr;
        _logger = logger;
        _userMgr = userMgr;
        _hasher = hasher;
        _config = config;
        _mapper = mapper;


    }

    protected async Task<string> GetUserId()
    {
        try
        {
            var userName = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
            {
                var user = await _userMgr.FindByNameAsync(userName);
                if (user != null)
                    return user.Id;
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting 404 error instead of 401, when token is expired or when token is not passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359027/getting-404-error-instead-of-401-when-token-is-expired-or-when-token-is-not-pas)

Comment: this solution not working with me

Comment: Ok, I retracted my close vote. I'm guessing the clue is the IIS vs IIS Express difference. Probably IIS is trying to redirect to an error page to report the 401, but when that isn't found, it throws a 404 that hides the 401.

Comment: this only happened when i use "app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error");" in startup.cs

Answer (score 6):

app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error") in startup.cs hide 401 un Authorized error .